# Understanding "ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(path))"

Tags: java, javax.imageio

My question is about the following code-example:

```
    public class BufferedImageLoader {

        private BufferedImage image;

        public BufferedImage loadImage(String path) throws IOException {

            image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(path));
            return image;

        }

    }
```

I looked in the Java-API and found 3 different read() methods in the ImageIO Class:

1.:
read(File input)

2.: read(ImageInputStream stream)

3.: read(InputStream input)

4.: read(URL input)

My question is: Which of them four methods is used in this example?
I'm a little bit confused, because in the example stands

```
read(getClass().getResource(path));
```

"getClass()" returns here "BufferedImageLoader", right?
Then we call the method "read(getClass().getResource(path))", which must stand in the BufferedImageLoader Class, but this is not the case!

Where i'm wrong?

Comment: `Object#getClass()` returns a `java.lang.Class` object. `Class#getResource(String)` returns a `java.net.URL` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getClass().getResource(path))` returns a `URL`, so in this case, it would using `ImageIO.read(URL)`

In addition, if you used `Class#getResourceAsInputStream`, it would return an `InputStream`, meaning it would be using `ImageIO.read(InputStream)` instead

Answer (score 0):

[getClass()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29) returns an typed instance of [java.lang.Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html), in your case `Class<? extends BufferedImageLoader>` which represent the `BufferedImageLoader` class. This method is inherited from [java.lang.Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) and returns the runtime class of the object.
The [getResource(path)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) method of `java.lang.Class` returns an instance of [java.net.URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
<Script = "JavaScript">
alert("Hello");
</Script>
```

alert('Selected items are removed successfully')