# Java Swing Maven - How to load ImageIcon in jar file

Tags: java, swing, maven, embedded-resource, imageicon

Here is my current directory structure (contained inside a `connect4` directory):

```
├── pom.xml
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   │   └── com
│   │   │       └── dv
│   │   │           └── app
│   │   │               ├── App.java
│   │   │               ├── Board.java
│   │   │               
|   |   |               
│   │   │               
│   │   └── resources
│   │       ├── red-chip.png
│   │       
│   └── test
│       ...            
|                     
└── target
    ├── classes/com/dv/app/*.class
```

Essentially from `Board.java`, I am trying to access `red-chip.png`.

I tried many variations for this to work, right now I just have:

`ImageIcon redChip = new ImageIcon("red-chip.png");`

I tried changing up the path to use `/resources`, used the `getResource` function, but nothing seemed to work.

When I generate the jar using `mvn package` and run the jar file, it does not show the image.

I perform `unzip -l <jar file>` and see that my red-chip.png has been moved to the root directory for some reason.

```
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
      126  2019-05-30 20:03   META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
        0  2019-05-30 20:03   META-INF/
        0  2019-05-30 19:19   com/
        0  2019-05-30 19:19   com/dv/
        0  2019-05-30 19:20   com/dv/app/
        0  2019-05-30 20:03   META-INF/maven/
        0  2019-05-30 20:03   META-INF/maven/com.dv.app/
        0  2019-05-30 20:03   META-INF/maven/com.dv.app/connect4/
     4190  2019-05-30 19:20   com/dv/app/App.class
     4975  2019-05-30 19:20   com/dv/app/Board.class
      110  2019-05-29 20:29   META-INF/maven/com.dv.app/connect4/pom.properties
     7856  2019-05-30 19:32   red-chip.png
```

Here is my `pom.xml`. Main thing to look at is the build jar plugin.

(removed useless stuff like artifactID, etc)

```
<project xmlns="...">
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>com.dv.app.App</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

So my questions are as follows:

1. What is the proper way to reference my png file so it will be visible in the jar?
2. Why was the png file located in the root in the jar?

Comment: This is common misconception. `ImageIcon(String)` actually exports the named value to be a file on file system, but your image is (hopefully) embed in the Jar. I’d avoid `ImageIcon` for at least this reason and use `ImageIO` instead. You need to use `Class#getResource` to get reference to the embedded resource

Comment: For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20891556/understanding-imageio-readgetclass-getresourcepath/20891595?r=SearchResults#20891595)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to load image as an icon for application your code should be like this. This will set the icon for your application.

```
this.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/red-chip.png")).getImage());
```

If you need to use `setIcon` method, you can use

```
ImageIcon IC = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/red-chip.png"));
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason that we reference `/red-chip` despite the path being inside the `resources` folder?

Comment: @KSplitX The contents of the `resources` folder are included in the Jar, but are not stored in a `resources` folder.  Also.  `ImageIO` is a better solution as it's blocking (won't return till the image is loaded) and will throw an exception if the image can't be loaded for some reason - which is infinitely better to resolve them `ImageIcon` when it does nothing